# Sorting an array of structs by 2 keys

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following data :

```
arTicker = [];
arTicker[1] = { "vid" : 100,
                "symbol" : "apple" };
arTicker[2] = { "vid" : 101,
                "symbol" : "dell" };
arTicker[3] = { "vid" : 102,
                "symbol" : "ibm" };                    
arTicker[4] = { "vid" : 110,
                "symbol" : "apple" };                        
arTicker[5] = { "vid" : 95,
                "symbol" : "apple" };                        
arTicker[6] = { "vid" : 115,
                "symbol" : "samsung" };    
arTicker[7] = { "vid" : 121,
                "symbol" : "dell" };      
arTicker[8] = { "vid" : 97,
                "symbol" : "apple" };    
arTicker[9] = { "vid" : 107,
                "symbol" : "ibm" };
```

I am trying to sort this array by symbol name and including the max vid for that symbol. In doing so, this is my desired output :

```
apple    | 110
dell     | 121
ibm      | 107
samsung  | 115
```

This is what I tried

```
arraySort(
    arTicker,
    function (e1, e2){
        return compare(e1.symbol, e2.symbol) // && e1.vid < e2.vid;
    }
);
writeDump(arTicker);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the source of this data?  Is QofQ an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit too much.

```
<cfscript>
    arTicker = [];
    arTicker[1] = { "vid" : 100, "symbol" : "apple" };
    arTicker[2] = { "vid" : 101, "symbol" : "dell" };
    arTicker[3] = { "vid" : 102, "symbol" : "ibm" };                    
    arTicker[4] = { "vid" : 110, "symbol" : "apple" };                        
    arTicker[5] = { "vid" : 95, "symbol" : "apple" };                        
    arTicker[6] = { "vid" : 115, "symbol" : "samsung" };    
    arTicker[7] = { "vid" : 121, "symbol" : "dell" };      
    arTicker[8] = { "vid" : 97, "symbol" : "apple" };    
    arTicker[9] = { "vid" : 107, "symbol" : "ibm" };     
    tracker = [];
    zeroPadding = '0000';
    finalArray = arTicker
        .sort(
            function (e1, e2){
                return compare(
                    e1.symbol & '-' & numberFormat(e1.vid,zeroPadding),
                    e2.symbol & '-' & numberFormat(e2.vid,zeroPadding)
                );
            }
        )
        .reduce(
            function (shell, element){
                shell[element.symbol] = element;
                return shell;
            },
            structNew( "ordered" )
        ).reduce(
            function (shell, key, element){
                shell.append(element);
                return shell;
            },
            []
        );
    writeDump(finalArray); 
</cfscript>
```

I am combining `symbol` and `vid` and comparing the combination as string. Since the `vid` is a number I am padding them with `0` to make it as the same length so that the sort of number as string does not cause issues.

Then from the sorted array create an `ordered struct` using `reduce`(struct will have the last item in the group of symbols which is the `max()`. Then use `reduce` on the structure again to get the array back.

[DEMO](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=e073aff9-563f-4409-a423-6ebbcd0b9e05/3d7e1414-2f16-4b70-9249-7e128d57a910/935e9087-de9b-483b-b1cf-ff7c39b03bd8.cfm)

For ***Coldfusion 11***, there are similar solutions.

```
//ArraySort mutates the array return true or false
ArraySort(
    arTicker,
    function (e1, e2){
        return compare(
            e1.symbol & '-' & numberFormat(e1.vid,zeroPadding),
            e2.symbol & '-' & numberFormat(e2.vid,zeroPadding)
        );
    }
);

finalArray = StructReduce(
    ArrayReduce(
        arTicker,
        function (shell, element){
            shell[element.symbol] = element;
            return shell;
        },
        {}
    ),
    function (shell, key, element){
        shell.append(element);
        return shell;
    },
    []
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but please take a look at the desired output. I need max(vid), symbol, group by symbol so to speak.

Comment: @CFNinja, I have made some updates. Might be useful.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am on ColdFusion 11. Fantastic solution though.

Comment: @CFNinja This might work in 11. I don't have an environment to test. [Demo](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=967047f4-ebd8-4903-aea6-e23f3f5870a4/54141d59-8cb0-42c0-b076-67f071787df1/de52feee-0139-4ad6-ab68-65fcf3051df5.cfm)

Comment: Epic! Thanks a million @rrk